# System.Runtime Assembly not found when referencing .net standard class library

Tags: asp.net, .net, xamarin, portable-class-library, .net-standard

Hopefully someone will be able to help.

I have a collection of projects that have recently been converted into .NetStandard 1.3 PCL's, this was done to allow my company's front end projects to share a communication layer with a new mobile project (Xamarin).

When these new PCL's are referenced in our WPF project everything runs fine, but referencing them in our ASP.net project cause a runtime exception.
[Runtime Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9U8p.png)

I found this was due to the System.Runtime.dll not being outputted to the bin folder of the project during build.

I have tried referencing the System.Runtime Nuget package directly in the project, but still nothing. 
After some investigation/hacking about I found that if I copy the (correct) System.Runtime.dll from the Nuget package and paste it manually into the bin everything loads.

So I then created a post build event that found and copied the missing dll's to the bin, but the dll's are still excluded from our deployment packages.

Is there anyway to get the needed dll's to be outputted to the bin directory during build like the rest of my dependencies?

I have read documentation on the .NetStandard and Googled this issue but havent managed to find anything that's helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same exact issue--I wasted about 5 hours trying to tinker with configuration files and NuGet packages, only to realize much to my chagrin that `System.Runtime.DLL` and `System.Runtime.Extensions.DLL` are not present in the `bin` directory.

I will write back if I have any breakthroughs.

--
EDIT: I don't know if this will help you, but I decided to start from square one, and recreate the PCL project and then re-add it to the solution. I set the PCL to target `netstandard1.3`; here's my `project.json` for the PCL:

```
{
  "name": "<redacted>",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "supports": {
    "net46.app": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "portable-net46+win8"
    }
  }
}
```

After doing this, and then adding the reference through the IDE, I do not get the assembly errors any longer. I am also able to link this PCL into my .NET Core 1.0 app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: PS. I found this tool very helpful; you can watch only assembly bindings that fail, and then see the exact list of paths that the loader is trying as it processes: [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)